# Download weather data by zip code tabulate area in R

Tags: r, download, weather

I am trying to figure out how to download weather(temperature,radiation,etc) by zip code tabulation area(ZCTA). Although Census data have census information by ZCTA, this is not the case for weather data.

I tried find information from http://cdo.ncdc.noaa.gov/qclcd/QCLCD?prior=N
but couldn't figure it out.

Has anyone of you ever downloaded the weather data by ZCTA? if not, has anyone had experience to convert weather observation station information to ZCTA?

Answer (score 2):

The National Weather Service provides two web-based API's to extract weather forecast information from the National Digital Forecast Database(NDFD), a [SOAP interface](http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/), and a [REST interface](http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/rest.php). Both return data in [Digital Weather Markup Language](http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/schema/DWML.xsd) (DWML), which is an XML dialect. Data elements which can be returned are listed [here](http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/docs/elementInputNames.php).

IMO the REST interface is by far the easier to use. Below is an example where we extract the forecast temperature, relative humidity, and wind speed for Zip Code 10001 (Lower Manhattan) in 3-hour increments for the next 5 days.

```
# NOAA NWS REST API Example
# 3-hourly forecast for Lower Mannhattan (Zip Code: 10001)
library(httr)
library(XML)
url <- "http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/sample_products/browser_interface/ndfdXMLclient.php"
response <- GET(url,query=list(zipCodeList="10001",
                               product="time-series",
                               begin=format(Sys.Date(),"%Y-%m-%d"),
                               Unit="e",
                               temp="temp",rh="rh",wspd="wspd"))
doc   <- content(response,type="text/xml")   # XML document with the data
# extract the date-times
dates <- doc["//time-layout/start-valid-time"]
dates <- as.POSIXct(xmlSApply(dates,xmlValue),format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
# extract the actual data
data   <- doc["//parameters/*"]
data   <- sapply(data,function(d)removeChildren(d,kids=list("name")))
result <- do.call(data.frame,lapply(data,function(d)xmlSApply(d,xmlValue)))
colnames(result) <- sapply(data,xmlName)
# combine into a data frame
result <- data.frame(dates,result)
head(result)
#                 dates temperature wind.speed humidity
# 1 2014-11-06 19:00:00          52          8       96
# 2 2014-11-06 22:00:00          50          7       86
# 3 2014-11-07 01:00:00          50          7       83
# 4 2014-11-07 04:00:00          47         11       83
# 5 2014-11-07 07:00:00          45         14       83
# 6 2014-11-07 10:00:00          50         16       61
```

It is possible to query multiple zip codes in a single request, but this complicates parsing the returned XML.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code! My problem is I need over 16 years hourly temperature(radiation) data by over 400 zcta. I probably need to figure out how to match the weather station to zcta and how to batch download data by each month.

Answer (score 1):

To get the NOAA QCLCD data into zip codes you need to use the latitude/longitude values from the station.txt file and compare that with data from Census.  This can only be done with GIS related tools.  My solution is to use a [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) enabled database so you can use the [ST_MakePoint](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) function:

```
ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude)
```

You would then need to load the ZCTA from Census Bureau into the database as well to determine which zip codes contain which stations.  The [ST_Contains](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Contains.html) function will help with that.

```
ST_Contains(zip_way, ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude))
```

A full query might look something like this:

```
SELECT s.wban, z.zip5, s.state, s.location
   FROM public.station s
   INNER JOIN public.zip z 
       ON ST_Contains(z.way, ST_MakePoint(s.longitude, s.latitude)
```

I'm obviously making assumptions about the column names, but the above should be a great starting point.

You should be able to accomplish the same tasks with QGIS (Free) or ArcGIS (expensive) too.  That gets rid of the overhead of installing a PostGIS enabled database, but I'm not as familiar with the required steps in those software packages.

Answer (score 0):

Weather data is only available for weather stations, and there is not a weather station for each ZCTA (the ZCTA's are much smaller than the regions covered by weather stations).

I have seen options on the noaa website where you can enter a latitude and longitude and it will find the weather from the appropriate weather station.  So if you can convert your ZCTA's of interest into a lat/lon pair (center, random corner, etc.) you could submit that to the website.  But note that if you do this for a large number of ZCTA's that are close together you will be downloading redundant information.  It would be better to do a one time matching of ZCTA to weather station, then download weather info from each station only once and then merge with the ZCTA data.

Comment: Thanks! Good suggestion! It might be a pain to match over 400 ZCTAs to weather station,but worth it if it can be reused in the future.